# A Process running in ec2 windows

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

recently I found that a process is keep running on one of our company's windows EC2(Windows server 2012 R2).

[image]

It takes up lot of resources from CPU. however, it disappear after I open the task manager for a few seconds.

Anyone has knowledge of what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your instance has been compromised and is **mining cryptocurrency**, explaining high CPU and magically disappearing when you want to look at its process.

More about the process [SystemManagement.exe](https://howtofix.guide/systemmanagement-exe-file/) is in the link.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will have a look into it.